# Taylor Series Calculating Program in C compiled with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, 32-bit

I have written a program in C that calculates the approximate value of the function exp(x) at various values of x, some positive and some negative. My questions are as follows:

1. Even though I was able to include 151 terms in the sequence before,
   now the series blows up for exp(100) even at the 140th term.
   Afterwards I messed up more with the code and now the series blows
   up even at the 130 term.  In addition to that I have used long
   double as the number format to allow large factorials to be
   calculated and displayed. How can one explain this phenomenon?
   Sometimes after successive execution of the code I get results
   approximating the real value of the function which I checked from
   Wolfram Alpha.
2. I have heard that "for" loops proved to be inefficient; do you have
   alternatives for "for" loop in mind? I would be happy to try to
   implement them as much as I can.
3. I want to display the output in scientific format but the format
   specifier (I am not sure about the term) did not allow me to do so.
   The specifier I used in printf statement was %g. How can I have the
   output displayed in scientific format?
4. Based on the hardware and software I am using is this the maximum
   precision I can get?
5. I also getting a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error instead of
   the display for x = -100. What may be the reason behind this?

Thanks for your contribution. I appreciate any help and recommendations.

P.S: I compile using GCC on 64-bit hardware, but 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (a.k.a Precise Pangolin).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//We need to write a factorial function beforehand, since we
//have factorial in the denominators.
//Remembering that factorials are defined for integers; it is
//possible to define factorials of non-integer numbers using
//Gamma Function but we will omit that.
//We first declare the factorial function as follows:
long double factorial (double);
//Long long integer format only allows numbers in the order of 10^18 so 
//we shall use the sign bit in order to increase our range.
//Now we define it,
long double
factorial(double n)
{
//Here s is the free parameter which is increased by one in each step and
//pro is the initial product and by setting pro to be 0 we also cover the
//case of zero factorial.
    int s = 1;
    long double pro = 1;
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Factorial is not defined for a negative number \n");
    else {
    while (n >= s) { 
    pro *= s;
    s++;
    }
    return pro;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    long double x[13] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100, -1, -5, -10, -20, -50, -100};
//Here an array named "calc" is defined to store 
//the values of x.
//The upper index controls the accuracy of the Taylor Series, so
//it is suitable to make it an adjustable parameter. However, after
//a certain value of p the series become infinitely large to be 
//represented by the computer; hence we terminate the series at 
//the 151th term. 
int p = 150;
long double series[13][p];
int i, k;
//We only define the Taylor series for positive values of the exponent, and
//later we will use these values to calculate the reciprocals. This is done
//in this manner to avoid the ambiguity introduced into the sum due to terms
//alternating in sign.
long double sum[6] = { 0 };
for (i = 0; i <= 6;i++) {

        for (k = 0; k <= p; k++){
        series[i][k] = pow(x[i], k)/( factorial(k));
        sum[i] += series[i][k];
}
printf("Approximation for x = %Lf is %Lf \n", x[i], sum[i]);
}
//For negative numbers -taking into account first negative number is
//in the 8th position in the x array and still denoting the approximation
long double approx[5] = { 0 };
for (i = 7; i <= 12;i++) {
    approx[i - 7] = 1 / sum[i - 7];
    printf("Approximation for x = %Lf is %Lf \n", x[i], approx[i - 7]);
}
//printf("%Lf \n", factorial(3));
//The above line was introduced to test if the factorial function
//was functioning properly.
}
```

Comment: Btw you have undefined behavior your loop runs for `i = 12` check `for (i = 7; i <= 12;i++)` then  `approx[i - 7]`  for i = 12 = `approx[5]` and max index value can be `5` only `long double approx[5] = { 0 };`

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand; can you elaborate on that? The approx array consists of 6 elements and each on is defined in my opinion.

Comment: for `i = 12` in last for loop condition `i <= 12;`  is = True so control executes expressions inside for-loop,  Put `i = 12` in `approx[i - 7] = 1 / sum[i - 7];` == `approx[5] = 1 / sum[5];` Now according to declaration `long double approx[5]`  max index can be just `4` indexing `approx[5] =` is  index  out of bound problem

Comment: Correct `long double approx[5] = { 0 };` as `long double approx[6] = { 0 };`

Comment: This the reason for `I also getting a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) e`

Comment: But substituting 6 for 5 did not resolve the issue.

Comment: then there must be other fault also..check edge values

Comment: And as I guess you have another mistake loop: `for (i = 0; i <= 6;i++) {` loop runs for `i = 6` and inside loop you index `i` in sun[] in expression `sum[i] += series[i][k];` --- `sum[6]` again array out of index problem.

Comment: Note array index start with `0` and max index value can be `size - 1`

Comment: No, that loop works almost perfectly. Yes I just confused the array dimension with array index :( By the way do you happen to know how to get out scientific notation from the printf statements? Many thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer some of your questions.

1 My eclipse code does not blow up.

2 I see no inherent inefficiency using for loops other than maybe too many iterations.

3 Use `"%Le"` for scientific format.

4 The maximum precision you can get will be about LDBL_EPSILON in 1.  Depends on your system that I do not know (maybe 1 part in power(2,64)).  Remember precision is relative, not absolute.

5 Segmentation Fault  likely due to `approx[5]`.  @Grijesh Chauhan

Suggestions

Add `-15` to `long double x[13+1] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100, -1, -5, -10, -15, -20, -50, -100 };`.  Change various other `13`s.

Add return to error condition:
`if (n < 0) { printf("Factorial is not defined for a negative number \n"); return 0; }`

Change to `long double approx[5+1+1] = { 0 };`

Add return to `main()`.

You get better numeric results if you add the small terms up first.  This usually means to reverse your `for (k = 0; k <= p; k++)` loop.

```
int main() {
  long double x[13+1] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100, -1, -5, -10, -15, -20, -50, -100 };
  int p = 150;
  long double series[13+1][p];
  int i, k;

  long double sum[6+1] = { 0 };
  for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k <= p; k++) {
      series[i][k] = pow(x[i], k) / (factorial(k));
      sum[i] += series[i][k];
    }
    printf("Approximation for x = %Le is %Le %e\n", x[i], sum[i], exp(x[i]));
  }

  long double approx[7] = { 0 };
  for (i = 7; i <= 12; i++) {
    approx[i - 7] = 1 / sum[i - 7];
    printf("Approximation for x = %Le is %Le %e\n", x[i], approx[i - 7], exp(x[i]));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well many thanks for your suggestions I will run through them and ask questions if I need to do so. I have measured my machine epsilon to be pow(2, -63) relatively by the way.

Comment: By the way the exp(100) term sometimes gets miscalculated and I do not know the reason behind this. The value seems to overshoot the limit of the long double as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Confident that your exp(100) problem is because `power(100,150)` or there abouts overflows.   Likely you are using a `double` version of `power()` and not a `long double` one.  Recommend a new approach: `(if k > 0) series[i][k] = series[i][k-1]*x[i]/k`.  No power function, no factorial function, no term computational limit, faster.

Comment: BTW: Suspect the number of terms needed somewhere 2 to 3.5 times the value of `x[i]`.  Using the above new approach above, for any x where exp(x) fits in a `long double`, your terms will not overflow.  I suspect `x` could be as large as 22,700.  Further, there really is no need to make an array for all the terms, just the current and previous ones.

Comment: I have changed pow function to powl and I was able to calculate up to 1755th term which gave very nice approximations. By the way does making an array prove inefficient?

Comment: @Vesnog Making an array, large or small, is usually not a _time_ inefficient process.  Of course an array has its _space_ efficiencies.